# Getting started with Microsoft Azure - local copy?

Tags: azure

Is there any ability to install a "development environment" for Azure, or a local equivalent that supplies all the same APIs, storage methods etc?

The end game is to not pay for Azure while I'm developing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [Azure SDK and Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1089b6-4050-4307-86c4-9dadaa5ed018) come with a local emulation environment that closely resembles real Azure and allows one to do most of development without ever deploying a single bit to Azure.

Emulation is provided for Roles and Azure Storage (Tables, Blobs, Queues).
If you need SQL Azure, suggestion is to use regular SQL Server and closely stick to compatible functionality only.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to the Windows Azure page to [download the SDK and tools](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/) - the installation is streamlined using the Web Platform Installer.

The local simulation environment simulates blobs, tables, and queues, as well as compute instances (although as separate processes, not as separate VM instances). The APIs all work in the local simulation environment.

To use SQL Azure, you'd need a real account. Same thing for the AppFabric services.

Just so you know: you can get a completely free account for 30 days, with SQL Azure, AppFabric services, and a few compute instances. Go to [www.windowsazurepass.com](http://www.windowsazurepass.com), and use promo code DPWE01.

EDIT: Agreed with Igor in his answer: you can develop with SQL Server and then push your database up to SQL Azure. The latest SQL Server Management Studio supports SQL Azure-compatible sql output scripts. As Igor points out, just stick to compatible SQL (which is a very large subset of SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is the way to go, but note, deploying worker role instances can be quite a bit more complicated, but testing locally once the SDK is installed, is fairly straight forward.